# How Do I Play An Audio Whenever I Click On a Specific Key On The Keyboard?

Tags: python, audio, pygame, keyboard, key

So, my idea is to create a **program** (**using the "*Keyboard*" module**) that, **while I am pressing on a key ("Enter", in this case), a sound is played (only once), as soon as I stop pressing that key, another sound would be played (only once).**
In other words, ***NASA* uses a communications system in which, when a "call" starts, a "*beeeep*" is played, when the "call" is ended (like an "*Over*") a "*beeeeep*" is played again.**
This was **my first attempt:**

```
import keyboard
import pygame

def BeepOn():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Mic On.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.50)

def BeepOff():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Mic Off.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.50)

while True:
    if keyboard.on_press_key('Enter'):
        BeepOn()

    if keyboard.on_release_key('Enter'):
        BeepOff()

    if keyboard.is_pressed('End'):
        exit()
```

Attention:
**I would like you to just have to click on one key instead of two.**
I hope I explained it well!
I look forward to an answer (however stupid it may be).
Regards,
Diogo Matos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
import pygame

#Condition for while loop
running = True



def BeepOn():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Mic On.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.50)

def BeepOff():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Mic Off.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.50)


while running:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            #Tests for quit
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            #Tests if enter is pressed
            if event.type = pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if Event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                BeepOn()

            #Tests if enter is released
            if event.type = pygame.KEYUP:
              if Event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                BeepOff()
pygame.quit()
```

I hope this helps, I'm not familiar with the keyboard module, so I just did it all from pygame. (:
If this helps please let me know...

Comment: Thanks, Man! 
I really appreciated. 
Your the best!
Greetings from Portugal!